# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' indexes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am constantly bothered by this problem, *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

which crashes my app. I hadn't got the problem before, but one day it started coming up, but since I have so many arrays, I don't even know where it comes from. Is there a way to tell the app not to crash on this error, or find the array that causes the problem??

By the way, every time I run the code I do this:

```
[messagename removeAllObjects];
[messageframe removeAllObjects];
[messagetext removeAllObjects];
[MapViewArray removeAllObjects];
[DeleteButtonArray removeAllObjects];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:reloadPath error:NULL];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:reloadInfoPath error:NULL];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:uploadPath error:NULL];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:uploadPathMap error:NULL];
```

This should clear all the arrays...

Answer (score 3):

You can set breakpoint to specific exception or all exceptions.
- Open Breakpoints Navigator (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>)
- Click <kbd>+</kbd> sign in the bottom
- Add exception breakpoint
- Optionally you can select only Objective-C exceptions

[Check Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/about_breakpoint_navigator.html)

Comment: It stops giving this result: 0x35067238:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}

Comment: If you have a crash broken in the debugger, you have a backtrace.  That 'push' is just the actual call to the throw.  Look up the stack to see the actual stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, you can set an exception breakpoint on "all objective-c exceptions". Then the debugger will break when the exception occurs and you can see where it happens.